# CompletionStage - thenX/thenXAsync : Same method signature, one compile and the other don't

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous

Using [CqlSession](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/CqlSession.html), I was led to us multiple [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html).

I first used [thenApply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) before I turned to [thenApplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApplyAsync-java.util.function.Function-), both provide same signature but when I use [thenApplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApplyAsync-java.util.function.Function-) my program doesn't compile any more and throw the below error.

> Error:(80, 22) overloaded method value thenApplyAsync with alternatives:
>     (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncResultSet, _ <: data.model.stored.Company],x$2: java.util.concurrent.Executor)java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[data.model.stored.Company] 
>     (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncResultSet, _ <: data.model.stored.Company])java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[data.model.stored.Company]
>    cannot be applied to (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncResultSet => data.model.stored.Company)
>         .thenApplyAsync[StoredCompany]((_: AsyncResultSet) => company)

After looking forward on the problem, the two methods should have the same final behavior (except that the async one deal with the function on an other thread, in this case supply by the session).

The problem is the same on every place I changed thenX to thenXAsync, there's an example part :

```
session
  .executeAsync(statement)
//.thenApplyAsync[Boolean](...) >> this one cause the error
  .thenApply[Boolean]({ set: AsyncResultSet =>
    optionRow(set) match {
      case Some(row) => row.getBoolean(CqlConst.AppliedColumnName)
      case None => throw new DataNotFoundException(id.toString)
    }
  })
```

The expected result would be no difference between the two (except a slightly less efficient execution for the asynchronous version)